# AWS S3 get object url from folder in the bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket named "video" on S3 and inside that bucket a folder named "thumb". I want to fetch url to image in "thumb" folder inside "video" bucket.

$object_key is image name with extension.

This code will look for that key inside bucket, but how do I make it look inside a folder in that bucket?

```
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'region'  => $region,
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => array(
            'key' => $key,
            'secret'  => $secret,
          )
    ]);

    $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $object_key
    ]);

    $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, $expire);
    $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

Comment: The key will be something like `thumb/dog.png`.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, there are no folders in S3. A bucket simply contains objects. It's a flat structure, but the AWS console shows an inferred folder hierarchy based on the `/` delimiter in the object keys for easier visualization and organization. If you check `list-objects` on the CLI, you can see that folders are in fact 0 byte sized objects.

So in short, the "folders" are part of the object key.